# Does this alternating series converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to prove the convergence of the following series:
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n\ln n}$$

I started by applying the alternating series test, and calculated
$$\left| \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n\ln n} \right| = \frac{1}{n\ln n} \to 0.$$

So, the alternating series must converge.

But the series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n\ln n}$ doesn't converge. So why does the alternate series converge?

Comment: Because the alternating series test applies.

Comment: I thought that if an alternate serie converges absolutely $\implies$ the serie not alternate converges.

Comment: If any series converges absolutely then the series converges. But if $\sum |a_n|=\infty,$ it does not imply $\sum a_n$ diverges.

Comment: The series is not absolutely convergent and is instead conditionally convergent. Many alternating series have this property, such as the alternating harmonic series.

Comment: @JeevanDevaranjan Ok. Now, I understand. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

The logical answer:
Because the series is alternating, you can apply the test for alternate series.
The other series is not alternating and thus the same argument does not apply.

The intuitive answer:
The problem with convergence in this case is whether the infinite sum reaches infinity. The non-alternating series gets to big, but the minuses in the alternating series makes sure that the series does not grow like crazy.

Remember that a convergent series is not necessarily absolutely convergent. This only holds the other way around.

Comment: Plenty of series never get large, such as $1-1+1-1+\cdots,$ but still diverge.

Comment: @zhw: True. But for positive series (or series with a tail behaving this way), getting "big" is the problem you want to avoid.